# How to calculate pyramid UV texture coordinates?

Tags: java, opengl, textures

I am trying to figure out a way to texture a pyramid in OpenGl and Java. All the tutorials I have read explain how to texture a cube, but not a pyramid.
These are the vertex positions I have set for the pyramid:

```
float[] pyramid =
  {
   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
  -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
   1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,

   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
   1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
   1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,

   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
   1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
  -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,

   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
  -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
  -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f
  };
```

and these are the UV coorinates I have set for it:

```
float[] uv = 
  {
  0.5f, 0.5f,
  0, 1,
  1, 0,

  0.5f, 0.5f,
  1, 0,
  1,0,

  0.5f, 0.5f,
  1,0,
  0,0,

  0.5f, 0.5f,
  1,0,
  0,1
  };
```

When I compile the texture looks very pixelized, as if I asserted wrong coordinates to a vertex. Could anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: any screenshot and the texture sample available?

Comment: when you map your texture to your pyramid you have quite a few ways you can do it, and it all depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i assume you mean to use one quarter of your texture on each face. to do that draw the unit square and enumerate the coordinate of each edge for the second and third coordinates. you should get something like ((0,0), (0,1)), ((0,1), (1,1)), ((1,1),(1,0)), ((1,0),(0,0))